# Atualizando os marcadores do Google Maps a cada 10 segundos!

Tags: jquery, ajax

Amigos, fiz um sisteminha de gravar os pontos no BD e depois exibí-los no mapa. Está funcionando normalmente, mas como fiz a gravação no BD via ajax, a página não é atualizada!

Eu estou fazendo desse jeito, mas atualizando a página toda:

```
//Gravar os dados no SQL, via AJAX
$('#formulario').submit(function() {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('arquivo', $('#arquivo').prop('files')[0]);
    form_data.append('txtLatitude', $('#txtLatitude').val());
    form_data.append('txtLongitude', $('#txtLongitude').val());
    form_data.append('txtObs', $('#txtObs').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'cadastrar.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#resultado').html(response);
            $("#resultado").fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(1000);
            $('input').val('');
            $('textarea').val('');
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location = "principal.php"
                },5000);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Para carregar os pontos no mapa, do PHP, estou usando o seguinte:

```
function carregarPontos() {

var json = <? echo $JSON ?>;

    $.each(json, function(index, ponto) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.latitude, ponto.longitude),
            title: "Meu ponto personalizado! :-D",
            map: map,
            icon: ''

        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker;

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        infowindow.setContent("<img width='80' src=" + ponto.foto + "><br>Foi visto: " + ponto.obs);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker))

    });
}

carregarPontos();
```

Como eu faria para poder atualizar a div com o novo ponto adicionado, logo após a inserção dos dados?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Não fique atualizando a cada 10 segundos. Use o mesmo método que usou para colocar cada ponto para adicionar o novo ponto logo antes ou depois de salvar por ajax.

Comment: Não entendi direito sua resposta amigo!

Comment: O que você não entendeu? Estou sugerindo que você crie um novo marker no mapa logo antes de salvar por ajax, usando um código parecido com o que você usou para criar marcadores com os dados do json.

Comment: Ahh sim, vou tentar aqui! Obrigado!

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui fazer, mas irei deixar como está! Assim que ele cadastra, ele atualiza a página! Obrigado @bfavaretto!